# get list of already printed labels from subplot elements to avoid double entries in legend

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, legend, subplot

Consider this function in Python:

```
def plots(fields, dev_data, plot_dict, width, color='b', offset=0, l=""):
    ii = 0
    for f in fields:
        ind = np.arange(len(dev_data[ii])) # the x locations for the groups
        import pdb
        plot_dict[f][1].bar(ind + offset, dev_data[ii], width, color=color, label=l, bottom=0)
        if (len(f)>1): #this is used to create a bottom ex. 
            plot_dict[f][1].bar(ind + offset, dev_data[ii+1], width, color='c', label= "free Memory", bottom=dev_data[ii])
            ii += 1
        ii += 1
```

It takes a list of input data (`dev_data`) and plots them as bars. `fields` is a list of tuple containing information about the data. Normally each tuple has one element but if it has 2, it means 2 subsequent data from `dev_data` must be plotted one above the other.

The function plots data on the `subplots` passed at each run. The problem is the following: if I call `plots` twice with the same list of `plt.subfigures`, it is executing this part:

```
           if (len(f)>1): #this is used to create a bottom ex. 
                plot_dict[f][1].bar(ind + offset, dev_data[ii+1], width, color='c', label= "free Memory", bottom=dev_data[ii])
                ii += 1
```

twice plotting the label with same values twice as shown in the figure.

To avoid this behaviour I want to get all the existing labels in the plot so that if already existing I will not pass the `label` argument to `bar` method, something like:

```
if (len(f)>1): #this is used to create a bottom ex. 
    if "free Memory" not in plot_dict[f][1].get_existing_labels():
        plot_dict[f][1].bar(ind + offset, dev_data[ii+1], width, color='c', label= "free Memory", bottom=dev_data[ii])
    else:
        plot_dict[f][1].bar(ind + offset, dev_data[ii+1], width, color='c', bottom=dev_data[ii])
    ii += 1
```

Does soemthing similar to `get_existing_labels`Is existing for matplotlib Axes class returning for example `['[0]', '[1]', 'free memory']`.?

Hope my question is clear.
Here is a minimal complete and verifiable example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
def plots(fields, dev_data, plot_dict, width, color='b', offset=0, l=""):
    ii = 0
    for f in fields:
        ind = np.arange(len(dev_data[ii])) # the x locations for the groups
        import pdb
        plot_dict[f][1].bar(ind + offset, dev_data[ii], width, color=color, label=l, bottom=0)
        if (len(f)>1): #this is used to create a bottom ex. (RAM_used, RAM_free)
            plot_dict[f][1].bar(ind + offset, dev_data[ii+1], width, color='c', label= "free Memory", bottom=dev_data[ii])
            ii += 1
        ii += 1

fields = [('avg_latency',), ('Successful requests',), ('CPU',), ('RAM', 'free RAM')]
dev_data  = [[8.583309839300817, 171.69371585480965, 1094.40896667813, 189.20147247618982], [100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0], [4.8860107086666815, 35.27584414319996, 76.51036722223547, 41.620512010866655], [1416.4132789999996, 1498.8874527999992, 1825.9473847058837, 3796.161298666671], [4585.911099999997, 4399.862112000003, 3348.1968705882373, 521.1009743727773]]
dev_data2  = [[8.583309839300817, 171.69371585480965, 1094.40896667813, 189.20147247618982], [100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0], [4.8860107086666815, 35.27584414319996, 76.51036722223547, 41.620512010866655], [1416.4132789999996, 1498.8874527999992, 1825.9473847058837, 3796.161298666671], [4585.911099999997, 4399.862112000003, 3348.1968705882373, 521.1009743727773]]

d = list()
d.append(dev_data)
d.append(dev_data2)

colors = ['y','b','r','g','y','c']
plot_d = dict(zip(fields,[ plt.subplots()for l in fields]))
width =0.2
l = ['a','b']
for ii, el in enumerate(d):
    plots(fields, d[ii], plot_d, width, colors[ii], width*(ii-1), [ii])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: legend element shown twice]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There indeed exist such function to get the legends and the handles. It is called `get_legend_handles_labels()` and applies to the current axis. This returns you the legend handles and the labels. The first element (index `[0]`) refers to the handles and the second element (index `[1]`) refers to the labels.

---

Specifically, use the following lines of code

```
import numpy as np
def plots(fields, dev_data, plot_dict, width, color='b', offset=0, l=""):
    ii = 0
    for f in fields:
        ind = np.arange(len(dev_data[ii])) # the x locations for the groups
        import pdb
        plot_dict[f][1].bar(ind + offset, dev_data[ii], width, color=color, label=l, bottom=0)
        if (len(f)>1): #this is used to create a bottom ex. 
            if "free Memory" not in plot_dict[f][1].get_legend_handles_labels()[1]:
                plot_dict[f][1].bar(ind + offset, dev_data[ii+1], width, color='c', label= "free Memory", bottom=dev_data[ii])
            else:
                plot_dict[f][1].bar(ind + offset, dev_data[ii+1], width, color='c', bottom=dev_data[ii])
            ii += 1
        ii += 1
```

[image]